# float:left and margin-left issue in ie6 and 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Please have a look at my IE issue pic:

[image: screenshot]

When I float the first `<div>` to the left and set the second `<div>` with `margin-left: 220px`, it works very well with FF and IE8. Yet in IE6 and 7 it doesn't work at all. My second `<div>` collapses and sits at the rightmost bottom of the first `<div>`. Here is HTML markup:

```html
<ol id="listingList">
    <li>
        <div class="media">
            .......
        </div>
        <div class="listingInfo">
            .......
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS code:

```css
#listingList div.media {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#listingList div.listingInfo {
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: 540px;
    color: #6A6A6C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listingList div.listingInfo {
float:left;
margin-left: 20px;
width:540px;
color:#6A6A6C;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when <div class="media"> doesn't exist, the second div will go to the left side. what I need is to set exactly the second div from first div 220px. Thanks for comments!

Comment: let me try it. I have remembered trying it out already. Not sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this to work with a minor amendment:

```
#listingList div.media {
    background-color: blue;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#listingList div.listingInfo {
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-left: 220px;
    width:540px;
    color:#6A6A6C;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Although you'll also have to correct the typo:

```
<did class="listingInfo">
```

should be

```
<div class="listingInfo">
```